# Make an Array from another array with using implode()

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array.

my array:

```
while($rowop = mysql_fetch_array($resultop))
{
    $info[] = array(
        'status'=>$rowop[2],
        'day' => $rowop[3],
        'from'=>$rowop[4],
        'to' => $rowop[5],
        'mon'=>$rowop[6],
        'tue' => $rowop[7],
        'wed'=>$rowop[8],
        'thu' => $rowop[9],
        'fri'=>$rowop[10],
        'sat' => $rowop[11],
        'sun'=>$rowop[12]
    );
}
```

value of `$rowop[6],$rowop[7],$rowop[8],$rowop[9],$rowop[10],$rowop[11],$rowop[12]` can be `'on'` or `'off'`.  I want to show only those rows which contain `'off'` value.  array will be same as:

```
'status'=>'ok',
'day' =>'all',
'from'=>'12pm',
'to' => '8am',
'off day'=>'tue,wed,thu,sat,sun'
```

Any one please give me Idea.if possible give example

Comment: Have you tried anything youself? Hint: take a look at [array_filter](http://nl3.php.net/array_filter).

Comment: You're definitely not concerned about `'status' => 'not ok'` but with one of the days `off`?  I think you should fix this in your query with group by instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, ( assuming your array name is `$info` ) :

```
$result = array();
foreach($info as $key=>$value){
    $result[$key]['status'] = $value['status'];
    $result[$key]['day'] = $value['day'];
    $result[$key]['from'] = $value['from'];
    $result[$key]['to'] = $value['to'];
    $off=array();
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        if($v=="off") $off[]=$k;
    }
    if($off) $off_days = implode (", ", $off);
    $result[$key]["off day"] = $off_days;
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: It's give blank result

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => Publish
            [day] => All Day
            [from] => 09:00
            [to] => 19:30
            [off day] => 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => Publish
            [day] => All Day
            [from] => 09:30
            [to] => 22:00
            [off day] => 
        )

Comment: maybe your array is blank, can you try `var_export($info)` and put the result in your question so I can debug your problem ?

Comment: if he put it after the while it will be okay

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$days = ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun'];
for($offs=[],$i=6,$i<=12,$i++) if($rowtop[$i]=='off') $offs[]= $days[$i-6];

$info[] = array(
     'status'=>$rowop[2],
     'day' => $rowop[3],
     'from'=>$rowop[4],
     'to' => $rowop[5],
     'off day' => implode(',', $offs)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about following code

I didn't test it. Fix if there are any errors

```
$days = array('mon','tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');
$selected = array();
$final = array();
foreach($days as $day)
{
    if(isset($info[$day]))
        if($info[$day] == 'off')
            $selected[] = $info[$day];
}

$all_days = implode(',', $selected);
$final['status'] = $info['status'];
$final['day'] = $info['day'];
$final['from'] = $info['from'];
$final['to'] = $info['to'];
$final['off day'] = $all_days;
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using `array_filter`

```
$days = array('mon','tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');

while($rowp ....) { //

$offs = implode (
            ',',
            array_keys(
                array_filter(
                    array_intersect_key($oneRow, array_flip($days)),
                    function($i) {return $i == 'off'}
                )
            )
);

//...

}
```

where `$oneRow` is what you are filling the `$info array with.`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in multiple steps:

- Find all keys with `off` status using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) and store it in array `$result`
- Remove all the "week keys", i.e. `mon`, `tue`, `wed` etc. using [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/array_diff_key)
- Implode `$result` array to get a comma-separated string, and use that to create a new array element

Code:

```
// find all keys with 'off' status
$status = 'off';
$result = array_keys(array_filter($info,
    function($element) use ($status) {
        return $element == $status;
    }
));

// remove all week keys
$keys = array('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun');
$info = array_diff_key($info, array_flip($keys));

// create a new array item with the comma-separated key string
$info['off_days'] = implode(',', $result);

print_r($info);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [status] => ok
    [day] => all
    [from] => 12pm
    [to] => 8am
    [off_days] => tue,wed,thu,sat,sun
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/95090)